# use condition in data frame with "with" function in R

Tags: r, with-statement

My data looks like this:

```
 manager     date country gender age q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 agecat
1       1 10/24/08      US      M  NA  5  4  5  5  5  NA
2       2 10.28/08      US      F  45  3  5  2  5  5  NA
3       3  10/1/08      UK      F  NA  3  5  5  5  2  NA
4       4 10/12/08      UK      M  39  3  3  4 NA NA  NA
5       5   5/1/09      UK      F  99  2  2  1  2  1  NA
```

Now I am trying to set agecat = "Elder" if age > 55. I tried the following two sets of codes and got different results:

Code 1 (worked)

```
leadership$agecat[leadership$age > 55] <- "Elder"
```

Code 2: (didn't work)

```
with(leadership, {
       agecat[age > 55] <- "Elder"
     })
```

Can anyone help me understand what's the difference between the two and why the second one doesnt' work? Many thanks!

Comment: Also look at the `cut()` function if you are trying to categorize a continuous variable.

Comment: ... and don't forget when using `within` to assign the results back to `leadership` ... or try `transform` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `with` expression

```
                 { 
    agecat[age > 55] <- "Elder"
}
```

returns the result invisibly, and since you haven't assigned it there is no change anywhere.  There are plenty of ways to do this, and using `with` in this situation actually seems a little clunky because you would have to do the following.  Notice the column is being given back on the second line of the expression.

```
leadership$agecat <- with(leadership, {
    agecat[age > 55] <- "Elder"
    agecat
})
```

Not really a streamlined `with` call, imo.  You could clean it up a bit with

```
leadership$agecat <- with(leadership, replace(agecat, age > 55, "Elder"))
```

which is basically the same thing just packed in a function.  But you could also use `within`, which updates the data and returns it back to you (so we would need to assign the result).

```
leadership <- within(leadership, agecat[age > 55] <- "Elder")
```

And as @BenBolker notes, `transform` is another option.  This gives the full updated data back as well, same as `within`.

```
leadership <- transform(leadership,agecat = replace(agecat, age > 55, "Elder"))
```

Long story short, it might be best to stick with your *Code 1* code for this.

Comment: ... `leadership <- transform(leadership,agecat = replace(agecat, age > 55, "Elder"))`

Comment: Appreciate the different options provided. all worked. This is great help, and thank you all for the answers!!

Answer (score 1):

`with` creates an environment for the data frame so that you do not need to retype the data frame name to access variables in it. In your case, you created a variable but it disappeared when you exit from the environment. Therefore, as Dirty Sock Sniffer said, use `within` that also creates an environment but returns the data frame. Thus the following works:

```
leadership <- within(leadership, agecat[age > 55] <- "Elder")
```